# Identifying colour codes for Viridis Palette - mako option G

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, visualization, viridis

On many of my images thus far, I have been using the viridis colour palette - Option G (or Mako).

I've been using functions to select from the palette, such as `scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "G")`.

However, I'd like to sample from this palette and therefore I'd like to identify the underlying colour codes.

Could anyone tell me how to identify the codes characterising Mako/Option G. So far, the function below has not worked.

Would appreciate all help.

```
#NOT WORKED. 
#I TRIED EXPANDING PARAMETER VALUES/CHANGING 'VIRIDIS' FUNCTION. YET, NO SUCCESS.  

library(viridis)
library(scales)
show_col(viridis_pal()(12))
```

Comment: its `show_col(viridis_pal()(12))`

Comment: Hi @Stephan. Typo, yes. I fixed that in the edit above. However, it still doesn't give me access to the mako/g palette when I expand the parameter values.

Comment: Hi @zx8754. Yeah, the hex colour codes for mako/Option G.

Comment: `viridis_pal(option = "G")(12)`

Comment: if you prefer RGB values, you can use `viridis.map()`

Comment: Hi @Stephan. Thanks for the answer. Helped a lot. Thanks also Paul and zx for suggestions. Much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
viridis_pal(option = "G")(12)
# [1] "#0B0405FF" "#231526FF" "#35264CFF" "#403A75FF" "#3D5296FF" "#366DA0FF"
# [7] "#3487A6FF" "#35A1ABFF" "#43BBADFF" "#6CD3ADFF" "#ADE3C0FF" "#DEF5E5FF"
```

---

Example:

```
#some plot with fill
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "G")
```

[image]

```
#get the codes used for above plot
viridis_pal(option = "G")(3)
# [1] "#0B0405FF" "#357BA2FF" "#DEF5E5FF"

#visualise the colours
show_col(viridis_pal(option = "G")(3))
```

[image]